# Nifi ExecuteScript with python: OOM exception

Tags: heap-memory, apache-nifi

One Trigger Processor->GenerateTableFetch->ExecuteSQLRecord->UpdateAttribute->ExecuteScript(python)->....
as pic
[image]

But Getting an OutOfMemory exception in ExecuteScript,What can i do?TIA

**Log**

```
2019-11-15 16:37:33,466 ERROR [pool-14-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Unable to checkpoint FlowFile Repository due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**Script**

```
import json
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, flowfile):
        self.ff = flowfile
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        # prop_col_names = self.ff.getAttribute('prop_col_names')

        prop_col_names = ['FACTORYNO']
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        obj = json.loads(text)

        results_prop = []
        results_basic = []

        for row in obj:
            main_id= row['COMBINEPICKUPNO']
            # main_prop_table
            for col_name in prop_col_names:
                # TODO: read from variable
                d = {}
                if col_name == 'FACTORYNO':
                    d = {'VALUE': row[col_name],
                         'ID': col_name,
                         }
                results_prop.append(d)
            # TODO: read from variable
            basic_info = {
                'ID': main_id,
            }
            results_basic.append(basic_info)

            results_pxp.append(pxp_info)
        data = {
            'prop': results_prop,
            'basic': results_basic
        }
        outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback(flowFile))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Java 1.8
Nifi 1.9.2

Comment: With following line `IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` you try to load full flow file content into a memory - that gives you out of memory... To suggest you something - we have to understand your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're reading huge files into memory, `daggett` is right that you can run out of memory.

Alternatively, I believe there are known memory leak(s) in Jython, but I couldn't find a page for the one I was looking for. You can try to set the system property `python.options.internalTablesImpl` to `weak` in bootstrap.conf and restarting NiFi.

As another possible option, since your script isn't too long, you could port the code to Groovy, it has many similar idioms as Python so hopefully wouldn't be too complicated.